# Ubuntu 23.10 Logitech mouse side buttons have stopped working

Tags: mouse, logitech

I have today upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 from 23.04 and the side buttons on my Logitech "Logi" M650 mouse no longer work. My 23.04 installation used Wayland as does the new 23.10. I cannot remember how I set up the side buttons in 23.04.

Can anyone show me how to set up the Logi side (extra) buttons in 23.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Logitech M650 side buttons can be configured under Wayland using the application **Input Remapper**. As this was already installed on my system I can only assume it is how I configired the buttons under ealier Ubuntu versions.